# PHP 5.5 Password Hashing API correct way to compare 2 password_hash() variables

Tags: php, hash, php-password-hash

I am setting up a registration form and am using the password hashing api, which from what i have read is currently the best way to protect passwords.

my form is

```
    <form action="register.php" method="post">
        <div class="fluid reg_firstname">
            <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
            <input name="first-name" type="text" style="width:90%;">
        </div>

        <div class="fluid reg_lastname">
            <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
            <input name="last-name" type="text" style="width:90%;">
        </div>

        <div class="fluid reg_email">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input name="email" type="text" style="width:50%;">
        </div>

        <div class="fluid reg_password">
            <label for="create-password">Create Password</label>
            <input name="create-password" type="password" style="width:70%;">
        </div>
        <div class="fluid reg_password">
            <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
            <input name="confirm-password" type="password" style="width:70%;">
        </div>

        <div class="fluid reg_agreement">
        <p>
        By clicking 'Submit' I agree that:
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>I accept the User Agreement- opens in a new window or tab.</li>
            <li>I give consent to the processing of my data- opens in a new window or tab.</li>
            <li>I may receive communications from SLF and I understand that I can change my notification preferences at any time in My Account.</li>
            <li>I am at least 18 years old.</li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="fluid reg_submit">
            <input name="step1" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

So i am adding some validtion to my form once the submit button is pressed which looks like this

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['step1']))
{
    #RETRIEVE VARIBLES
    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['first-name']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['last-name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
    $password1 = password_hash($_POST['create-password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $password2 = password_hash($_POST['confirm-password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


    #VALIDATION CHECKS

    if($first == "")
    {
        $error[] = "Please Enter First Name";
    }
    if(strlen($first) < 2 OR strlen($first) > 16)
    {
        $error[] = "Name between 2 and 16 chars long";
    }
    if(!ctype_alnum ( $first ))
    {
        $error[] = "Letters Only Please";   
    }       

    if($last == "")
    {
        $error[] = "Please Enter Last Name";
    }
    if(strlen($last) < 2 OR strlen($last) > 16)
    {
        $error[] = "Surname between 2 and 16 chars long";
    }
    if(!ctype_alnum ( $last ))
    {
        $error[] = "Letters Only Please";   
    }

    if($email == "")
    {
        $error[] = "Please Enter Vaild Email";
    }
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
        $error[] = "Invalid email format";
    }

    if($password1 == "")
    {
        $error[] = "Please enter a valid password";
    }   

    if($password1 <> $password2)
    {
        $error[] = "Passwords Dont Match";
    }


    if(isset($error) && (count($error) >0))
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($error);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    echo "step one complete<br />";
    echo $password1."<br />".$password2;
}?>
```

the trouble im having is with my password check

```
if($password1 <> $password2)
{
    $error[] = "Passwords Dont Match";
}
```

im checking if the two varibles match but im guessing because i have added the password_hash to them it is checking the hash value and not the actual value entered by the user? how would i correct this so it checks the actual data and not the hash value (which will never match)?

appreciate any help!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test the original data, then why not just actually test the original data?

```
if($_POST['create-password'] <> $_POST['confirm-password'])
{
    $error[] = "Passwords Dont Match";
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `create-password = '0'` and `confirm-password = 'abc'`... now compare using this code.... better to use type-sensitive `!==` than loose-typed comparison `<>`

Comment: rjdown - yeah that would work :) for some reason i was over complicating things as per usual, thanks for your answer!! thanks mark baker for your suggestion too :)